# Line/String comparison ignore certain section of string of variable length with characteristic start and ending words in Perl

Tags: perl, comparison, line

I'd like to compare two lines from 2 different files. But I'd like to ignore any section of the line that starts with the word "SubmissionTime:" and ends with word "execEndTime:".For example

if

```
$line1="TestSubmissionTime123execEndTime"  
$line2="TestSubmissionTime1234567789012131231execEndtime"
```

these 2 lines should be equal. so there may be a variable amount of data between submissionTime and execEndTime. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you can easily remove the unneeded data from the strings by something like this:

```
sub compare_by_my_rules {
  my ($line1, $line2) = @_;
  $line1 =~ s/(?<=SubmissionTime).+?(?=execEndTime)//g;
  $line2 =~ s/(?<=SubmissionTime).+?(?=execEndTime)//g;
  return $line1 cmp $line2;
}
```

In other words, the strings passed into this routine have their offending sections removed by using lookarounds - `lookbehind` for 'SubmissionTime', `lookahead` for 'execEndTime' - and then compared. But in fact you can remove the whole block with:

```
  =~ s/SubmissionTime.*?execEndTime//g;
```

... as these markers are destined to be equal and won't affect the comparison at all.

`.*?` is used to process the strings with more than a single SubmissionTime section.

Comment: Oops, didn't see you already answered this...

Comment: The original strings will stay intact no matter what you do, you are only using copies of them.

Comment: @raina77ow: I wouldn't be so sure that the intervening text is always numeric and non-null. I also see no point in keeping the delimiting strings.

Comment: Yes, of course, they're copies. I noted that because if the same code will be used just as is (not in a sub), the lines will be modified.

Comment: @Borodin You're right, of course; will update my answer. And why I was thinking that we should remove only digits - and why we have to remove only them, in fact?

Comment: @raina77ow: It is hard to judge whether the digit strings in the question are examples or just placeholders. Either way it seems safer to match any characters between the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting anything between submissionTime and execEndTime and then comparing. For example:

```
my $line1 = "TestSubmissionTime123execEndTime";
my $line2 = "TestSubmissionTime1234567789012131231execEndTime";

$line1 =~ s/TestSubmissionTime.*execEndtime//;
$line2 =~ s/TestSubmissionTime.*execEndTime//;
if $line1 eq $line2 {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good job for a subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line1="TestSubmissionTime123execEndTime"; 
my $line2="TestSubmissionTime1234567789012131231execEndtime" ;

print comp($line1, $line2) ? "Same" : "Not same";

sub comp {
    my ($str, $cmp) = @_;
    $str =~ s/SubmissionTime.*?execEndTime//ig;
    $cmp =~ s/SubmissionTime.*?execEndTime//ig;
    return ($str eq $cmp);
}
```

I used the `/i` (ignore case) modifier since your sample strings contain both `Endtime` and `EndTime`, and you said they should be equal. If this is a typo, and case is important, remove `/i`. I used the global `/g` modifier to remove all occurrences of these strings.

The original strings will not be altered.